# What's a good SVN service?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm considering shopping for SVN services.  There's only 2 developers here and we need minimal services, like 500 MB disk space would probably be plenty, we don't care about any tracs or wikis or anything like that - though if it had one that'd be a bonus.  Email updates on commits are a necessity.

Comment: Although not SVN, have you considered github?

Comment: Yeah, the pricing for what we need is $7/mo.  There are services out there that charge less than half that.

Comment: Those services probably have a subset of 10 times the downtime, poor support when things go wrong, higher latency and lower bandwidth to name a few. That might not bother you, but if it does do reconsider github. It's fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google found [this](http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/) for me.

Answer (score 1):

[RepositoryHosting](http://repositoryhosting.com/) is very affordable and provides `svn`, `hg` and `git`.

Answer (score 1):

A client of mine uses ProjectLocker.com. Their free plan allows 3 users, 500Mb, and up to 3 projects. They support *git* and *Subversion*.

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experiences with [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you require the resource of a $7/month plan at [github.com](http://github.com), then consider [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org) which has unlimited public and private repositories, with room for 5 collaborators.